# Spring Security check if specific user(s) are online

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to write a function that shows if certain users are currently authenticated with Spring Security. Basically, just to display if a certain user is logged in right now.

I know I can get all logged in users via `sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()`, but what I just want to see if a specific user is logged in right now (e.g. on their profile page).

Is there a built-in function for this? If not, where's an entry point I can use to implement this functionality myself?

Comment: If you don't want to iterate over the session registry you may wrap it inside a custom implementation (so that you can tamper with the registerNewSession method) so that you can keep a reference of all the principals (when they are registered) using the key that you prefer (userId?) and implement a getPrincipalByKey(Key key) to get the interested principal.

Comment: Alright, thank you, I'll leave it at iterating the session registry for now.